# Get specific values from Firebase Realtime and collect their values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I get specific values from Firebase Realtime and collect all of them to show the user the total value of all children inside the sales list
android studio - with java

Get specific values from Firebase Realtime and collect their values android studio - with java

[image]

```
public class SalesFragment extends Fragment {

TextView otherSalesValue, otherEarnsValue;

DatabaseReference databaseReference;

int sale;

String currentUserId;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sales, container, false);

    currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("sales");

    otherSalesValue = root.findViewById(R.id.other_sales_value);
    otherEarnsValue = root.findViewById(R.id.other_earns_value);

    databaseReference.child(currentUserId)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot uniqueKeySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot booksSnapshot : uniqueKeySnapshot.child("total").getChildren()) {
                    String sales = booksSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    try {
                        sale = Integer.parseInt(sales);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    sale = +sale;

                    otherEarnsValue.setText(String.valueOf(sale));
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly would you like to count? What is the expected result?

Comment: I want to sum all "total" values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sales` node you read has two dynamic child levels under it, so you need two nested loops over `getChildren()` before you can get the `total` property.

```
databaseReference.child(currentUserId)
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot dateSnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                     //  loop over all child nodes
                long totalValue = dateSnapshot.child("total").getValue(Long.class);
                                                     //  get the total for this date

                sale = sale + totalValue; //  add the daily total to the sum
            }
        }
        otherEarnsValue.setText(String.valueOf(sale));
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); //  never ignore errors
    }
});
```

---

Note that if all you need it the sum of the daily totals, it is quite wasteful to read all the additional data in each client.

Consider storing a running total in a higher-level node the database too (maybe in `/sales_total`) and updating that whenever you also update the daily total. Keeping data in multiple places like this is quite common in NoSQL databases, and is part of the reason their read operations scale so well.